# Insert text in a new file with a specific extention

Tags: vim

I'd like vim to do the following when opening a new file:

1. check the extension
2. if the extension is .hpp continue otherwise break
3. insert a line `#pragma once`

So basically, I want vim to give an automatic header when it opens the file depending on an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following examples are given under `:help skeleton`:

```
To read a skeleton (template) file when opening a new file: >

  :autocmd BufNewFile  *.c      0r ~/vim/skeleton.c
  :autocmd BufNewFile  *.h      0r ~/vim/skeleton.h
  :autocmd BufNewFile  *.java   0r ~/vim/skeleton.java
```

If you really want just a single line, then you could use

```
:au BufNewFile *.hpp call append(0, '#pragma once')
```

or

```
:au BufNewFile *.hpp put!='#pragma once' | $
```